# Containment among operations on ideals: product, direct sum, intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is the relationship $IJ \subseteq I \cap J \subseteq I, J \subseteq I + J$ correct?

Quick sketches:

#### 1. $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$

Elements of $IJ$ are linear combinations of the form $\sum_k i_k j_k$. Ideals are closed under multiplication with the whole ring, thus each $i_k j_k = i_k'$ Ideals are also closed under addition. Thus, each term in $\sum_k i_k j_k = \sum_k i'_k = i'' \in I$. Similarly, we can group terms according to $J$ to arrive at $\sum_k i_k j_k = \sum_k j_k' = j'' \in J$.

#### 2 $I \cap J \subseteq I, J$

Immediate from definition of intersection.

#### 3. $I, J \subseteq I + J$

each $i \in I$ can be written as $(i \in I) + (0 \in J)$ which is an element of $i + j$. Similarly with $J$.

Is there some way to organise these containments into a nice exact sequence? In general, I find that I have to pause and think before I remember these relations. Is there some way to organise these better?

Comment: Your proof is fine, and can be regarded as the standard way to dispatch that exercise. No need for an alternate approach. On to the next problem!

Comment: Your proofs of the statements are very short - I’d say short enough that it’s fine to just remember the argument each time you need one of the inclusions. As you practice, that process will become faster and faster, until eventually you don’t have to think about it at all.