# Exact sequence of ideals: intersection, product, direct sum, sum

Tags: ring-theory, modules, solution-verification, ideals, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be  ring, $I, J$ be ideals. I believe this exact sequence is valid. Can someone verify this for me?

$$
0 \rightarrow IJ \xrightarrow{f} I \cap J \xrightarrow{g} I \oplus J \xrightarrow{h} (I + J) \rightarrow 0 \\
f: IJ \rightarrow I \cap J\quad f(r) \equiv r \\
g: I \cap J \rightarrow I \oplus J \quad g(r) \equiv (r \text{ mod } I , r \text{ mod } J) \\
h: I \oplus J \rightarrow I + J\quad h(i, j) \equiv i + j \\
$$

- It is clear that $f: IJ \rightarrow I \cap J$ is injective, since $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$. ([For a proof, see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704125/containment-among-operations-on-ideals-product-direct-sum-intersection))
- It is clear that $h: I \oplus J \rightarrow I + J$ is surjective, since every element in $i + j \in I + J$ is the image of $(i, j)$: $(i, j) \overset{h}\mapsto (i + j)$.

The part I am unsure of is that of $(g,h)$. Let me attempt the proof: We need to  show that $Im(g) = Ker(h)$. That is:

1. $Im(g) \subseteq Ker(h)$

$$
g: I \cap J \rightarrow I \oplus J \quad g(r) = (r \text{ mod } I , r \text{ mod } J) \\
Im(g) = \{ (r \text{ mod } I, r \text{ mod } J) : r \in I \cap J \}  \\
\text{(Since $r$ is in the ideals $I, J$, residue is $0$)} \\
Im(g) = \{ (0, 0)  \} \quad \\
Im(g) \subseteq Ker(h)
$$

2. $Ker(h) \subseteq Im(g)$

$$
h: I \oplus J \rightarrow I + J\quad h(i, j) \equiv i + j \\
h((i, j)) = 0 \\
i + j = 0 \\
-i = j \\
\text{($j$ is a multiple of $i$; Ideals closed under multiplication)} \\
j \in I \\
(i, j) \in I \cap J \\
(i, j) \in Im(g)
$$

Hence we conclude that $Im(g) = Ker(h)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $g$ is just the zero map, right?

Comment: Right, on simplification, that is what it is. But I want to think of it as  $r \mapsto (r, r)$, which simplifies to $r \mapsto (0, 0)$.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was shown that this exact sequence is incorrect. Note that the image of $g: I \cap J \rightarrow I \oplus J$ is just $\{ 0 \}$, while the kernel of $h: I \oplus J \rightarrow I + J$ contains pairs $(i, -i)$. So, $Im(g) \neq Ker(h)$, and hence the sequence is not exact.